# Roles in zend not functioning

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl, roles

Here is my module.config.php

```
class Module
{
    protected $whitelist = array(
        'home',
        'user/login',
        'job/view',
    );

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $serviceManager      = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        // Authentication service
        $auth = $serviceManager->get('AuthService');

        // Authorization (ACL)
        $this->initAcl($e);
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($auth) {
            $route = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
            //$auth->getIdentity();
            // Retrieve logged in user role

           $userRole = $auth->getIdentity()->level;
            if ($userRole == '1')
            {
                $userRole = 'admin';
                echo "admin";
            }
            elseif ($userRole == '2'){
            $userRole = 'manager';
            //echo "manager";
            }

           elseif ($userRole == '3'){
            $userRole = 'hrstaff';
           echo "hrstaff";
           }

         //   $userRole = ($auth->getIdentity()->level === '1') ? 'admin' : 'manager';

            if ($e->getViewModel()->acl->hasResource($route) && !$e->getViewModel()->acl->isAllowed($userRole, $route)) {
                $response = $e->getResponse();

                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $e->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/404');
                $response->setStatusCode(303);
            }
        });

        $list = $this->whitelist;

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($list, $auth) {
            $match = $e->getRouteMatch();

//             // No route match, this is a 404
//             if (!match instanceof RouteMatch) {
//                 return;
//             }

            // Route is whitelisted
            $name = $match->getMatchedRouteName();
            if (in_array($name, $list)) {
                return;
            }

            // User is authenticated
            if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
                return;
            }

            $router = $e->getRouter();
            $url = $router->assemble(array(), array(
                'name' => 'user/login'
            ));

            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
            $response->setStatusCode(302);

            return $response;
        }, -100);


    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function initAcl(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $acl = new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl();
        $roles = include __DIR__ . '/config/module.acl.roles.php';
        $allResources = array();

        foreach ($roles as $role => $resources) {
            $role = new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole($role);
            $acl->addRole($role);

            $allResources = array_merge($resources, $allResources);

            // Adding resources
            foreach ($resources as $resource) {
                $acl->addResource(new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource($resource));
            }

            // Adding restrictions
            foreach ($allResources as $resource) {
                $acl->allow($role, $resource);
            }
        }

        $e->getViewModel()->acl = $acl;
    }
}
```

and here is my module.acl.roles.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'manager' => array(
        'home',
        'job',
        'user/password',
    ),
    'admin' => array(

    ),
    'hrstaff' => array(
            'user',
            'user/add',
    ),

);
?>
```

before that there were only 2 roles, Manager and Admin then I try to add the hrstaff role and try to add modules on the array but unfortunately it didn't effect, the hrstaff only inherits the role of Manager and I dont know why, then I try to cut and paste the modules of Admin to hrstaff to test it but it didn't effect also, the result is still the same. Am I missing something? Thanks in Advance!